# Why CROSS APPLY not working properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a temporary table with dates and asset prices. I wanted to calulate daily returns. It works perfectly when I used LAG(), but when I use CROSS APPLY, then something goes wrong. Could somebody explain where is my mistake?

```
CREATE TABLE #returns (Data Date, s Float);

INSERT INTO #returns (Data, s) VALUES ('20120618', 142), ('20120619', 122), ('20120620', 145), ('20120621', 148), ('20120622', 111);

SELECT *
FROM #returns

SELECT Data, (s/LAG(s) OVER(ORDER BY Data) -1)
FROM #returns


SELECT tLater.Data, (tLater.s / tPrev2.s) - 1
FROM #returns as tLater
CROSS APPLY
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 tPrev.s
    FROM #returns as tPrev
    WHERE tPrev.Data < tlater.Data
    ORDER BY tPrev.Data
   ) as tPrev2
```

Comment: 'Something goes wrong'. What is that something?

Comment: You have to 1) Use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` so as to get 1st record, which has no previous record, as well and 2) use `ORDER BY DESC` to get previous record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are alomst there, change the cross apply to outer apply and the statement within the  Outer Apply should be an orderby desc.

```
SELECT tLater.Data, (tLater.s / tPrev2.s) - 1
FROM #returns as tLater
OUTER APPLY
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 tPrev.s
    FROM #returns as tPrev
    WHERE tPrev.Data < tlater.Data
    ORDER BY tPrev.Data DESC
   ) as tPrev2
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you use `<` in `CROSS APPLY` (or a correlated subquery), you want the *largest* value not the *smallest*.  My guess is that you have the ordering wrong:

```
SELECT tLater.Data, (tLater.s / tPrev2.s) - 1
FROM #returns tLater CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 tPrev.s
      FROM #returns as tPrev
      WHERE tPrev.Data < tlater.Data
      ORDER BY tPrev.Data DESC
--------------------------^
     ) tPrev2;
```